# Populating a ListView with parse.com

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I'm building an app that would display the the values from column "NameMessage" from the table/class "messages" from my parse.com app called : "ParseQueryAdapter" on the click of "Display" button. Nothing happens when display button is clicked, and the app crashes when the display button is clicked the 2nd time. I'm also attaching the logcat. Please help. Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
private ListView listView;
private EditText textName;
private EditText textMessage;
private Button buttonSendInfo;
public double plong;
public double plat;
private Button buttonDisplay;
 ArrayList<String> messagesarray = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Parse.initialize(this, *HIDDEN FOR SAFETY*);



textName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
buttonSendInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
buttonDisplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
buttonDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        populatelist();
        }
        }

protected void populatelist() {
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> NameMessage, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null){
            for(int i = 0;i<NameMessage.size();i++){

                messagesarray.add(NameMessage.get(i).toString());




            }

        }
        else {Log.d("Messages","Error:"+e.getMessage());}

    }


    });

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.id.myList,R.layout.list_item,messagesarray));    
}

}
```

***LOGCAT:***

```
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080007 type #0x12 is not valid 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:934) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
10-14 04:53:02.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the [screenshot][1] of my table.

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/1958582_10152484345338178_1225744402895431728_n.jpg?oh=f5170a80b5336193a28f86ed1293268e&oe=543F72BC&**gda**=1413426615_2ae1ecb312ef73ff1dd20ee5d006d753](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/1958582_10152484345338178_1225744402895431728_n.jpg?oh=f5170a80b5336193a28f86ed1293268e&oe=543F72BC&__gda__=1413426615_2ae1ecb312ef73ff1dd20ee5d006d753)

Comment: Screenshot unavailable, please upload it here.

Comment: I saw the same question yesterday...

Comment: yes Pedro and i made changes to my code and now im getting different errors. And i've changed the screenshot link please check. i cant upload here. need 10 reputation points for that

Comment: Show us your imports

Comment: You're not importing R.

Comment: @PedroOliveira he is, but he is not reading the doc: `ArrayAdapter constructor ...resource - The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
textViewResourceId - The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated...` next question will be: why i'm getting NPE exception ... because messagesarray is null at the time of adapter creation

Comment: Adding "import.android.R;" has made every line ofcode which has R in it as an error.
eg: activity_main cannot be resolved.

Comment: You shouldn't import android.R. You should import your generated R. Not android's. Also @Selvin is right.

Comment: Could you Please explain how I can do that ?  And how to deal with wha @Selvin is saying ?